# I have a difficulty to write a constraint with binary variable

Tags: cplex, opl

I am new in Cplex and look for your help to write the following constraint in Cplex OPL:

[image]

Note that x is dvar, d is parameter (demand). y is a binary variable equal to 1 if mode m is used in period t, and 0 otherwise.

Comment: Please share more details, like the code involved

Comment: Thank you I found help from Alex ....However I cannot solve the whole problem

Answer (score 0):

```
int Tmax=7;
int Mmax=5;

range T=1..Tmax;
range M=1..Mmax;

int d[T]=[1,4,6,8,9,2,3];

dvar int+ x[T][M];
dvar boolean y[T][M];

subject to
{
  forall(t in T,m in M) x[t][m]<=y[t][m]*sum(tprime in t..Tmax)d[tprime];
}
```

works fine

Comment: I tried to solve the whole problem but I always received errors ....can I find help (sometimes name t does not exist and other p does not exist....):